# Посчитать среднее значение по двум столбцам фрейма данных

Tags: python, функции, pandas

Задача: Посчитайте среднее время жизни пользователей, которые выставили более 100 оценок.
Вопрос: Как посчитать разницу между вложенными столбцами max и min? Как оформить это в коде? Пробовала написать функцию и применить её к df, но не пойму что передать в аргумент. Буду благодарна за помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разницу посчитать просто `df["max"] - df["min"]` только непонятно как это вам поможет посчитать __среднее__

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то такое будет::

```
df100 = df.loc[df['count'] > 100]
mean = (df100[('timestamp','max')] - df100[('timestamp','min')]).mean()
```

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, не сообразил про эту засаду )

Answer (score 3):

Для доступа к вложенным столбцам можно воспользоваться [pd.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html).

Пример:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A      -0.502487  0.491691  1.379375 -0.688359  0.212742  0.526236 -0.086782 -0.617966
B       0.560005  0.084704 -0.049344  0.657484 -0.179556  1.410070  0.064947 -1.119560
C       0.166898  1.014669  0.902663 -0.362594 -1.698073  0.504725 -2.057105  0.524396

In [42]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [43]: df.loc[:, idx["bar", "two"]] - df.loc[:, idx["bar", "one"]]
Out[43]:
A    0.994179
B   -0.475301
C    0.847772
dtype: float64
```